# What are the types of error correlation?

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, clustered-standard-errors, spatial-correlation

In many fundamental regression models errors are assumed Independent Identically Distributed.

One of violations of this assumption is when the errors are somehow correlated. From what I know it may take many forms, from which I happened to encounter three:

- Serial correlation.
- Clustering.
- Spatial correlation.

Are there some other "general" manifestations of possible error correlations? Hopefully there is some review that aims at exhausting this topic?